# Esri Distance Calculation

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

What is the difference of using `esri/geometry/geometryEngine` [distance method](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/esri.geometry.geometryengine-amd.html#distance) and `GeometryService` [length method](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/geometryservice.html#lengths)? Which is faster and capable of calculating distance on Mouse Move event on client side in JS API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `geometryEngine` should be faster as it runs client side.  Although there would be the slight slow down as the module gets loaded during your site's initialization, you don't need to wait for a callback function as you would with the `GeometryService`.

If you're doing it with the mouse move event, definitely stay client side with `geometryEngine`.

Answer (score 3):

@Branco is right, but its also important to note that the geometryEngine distance and length methods are only capable of generating geodesic calculations for WGS84 and Web Mercator maps.  As such the clientside library should **not** be used to calculate planar measurements in map projections that distort distance.

see [this blog](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2015/09/16/geometryengine-part-2-measurement/) for more information.

Comment: So this is true for all `geometryEngine` methods? I'm trying unsuccessfully to use `nearestCoordinate` with a projected layer, but no chance it's going to work then ? Is there any other alternative for finding the closest feature for a clicked location? Pity this isn't explained clearly in the doc, I've lost a lot of time.